# Node.JS Child Process exec strange behaviour

Tags: node.js, child-process

When I execute a command in terminal it lasts ~5s, but when I use `require('child_process').exec` with a 1 minute timeout it returns `[Error: Command failed: ] killed: true, code: null, signal: 'SIGTERM'` after 1 minute?

P.S. that command generates some files and in both cases the output is ok.

**Update**: example of such behaviour:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
exec('docker run --rm -i ubuntu sleep 1',
  {timeout:15000},
  function(){
    console.log(arguments)
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you share the node exec code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d7e533cb188944376b09
it's about docker.io

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `-i` flag, it will work fine.

The `-i` "interactive" flag in Docker causes the `STDIN` to be opened and the exec won't like it by default.